# webpack localhost/sockjs.js.map not found

Tags: webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have the following error regarding socks.js.map, can anyone help me?

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

I installed the latest version of the webpack and webpack-dev-server and configured it like this:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {
    entry : './index.js',
    output : {
        path: __dirname + '/public',
        filename : './bundle.js'
    },
    devServer: {
        port: 8080,
        contentBase: './public'
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /.js?$/,
            loader: 'babel-loader',
            exclude: /node-modules/,
            query: {
                presets : ['es2015']
            }
        }]
    }

}
```

My package.json is with a script:

```
"dev": "webpack-dev-server --progress --colors --inline --hot"
```